# Django project not opening in PyCharm due to strange error with \.idea\workspace.xml?

Tags: xml, django, pycharm, blue-screen-of-death

I'm getting this error when trying to open my project on PyCharm community edition. The thing is, the project was opening fine on PyCharm until (literally 30 mins ago) a blue screen error hit ("dumping physical memory into disk, etc) and my windows7 x64bit PC just restarted. After restarting, PyCharm is throwing this error. Weird part is, I've checked the XML file on my Notepade++ and there are no open  tags that need to be closed (let alone line 204). In fact, Notepadd++ search returns only 3 instances of `<state>` but 70 instances of `</state>`. And all instances of `<state>` are lines 300+ (305,308,313).

```
\.idea\workspace.xml': Error on line 204: The element type "state" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</state>"
```

I really cant work on this project on Notepad, please help me with getting this back up on PyCharm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `.idea\workspace.xml` got corrupted during the windows crash. It's possible that other project files in the `.idea` dir and/or in the source code itself may be corrupted as well.

Before anything else I'd exit pycharm and make a copy of the entire project dir (think disaster recovery) which can be cloned as many times as needed during recovery attempts.

If you have your source code and/or the `.idea` under a version control system you could restore the most recent committed version from there and maybe even recover some of the uncommitted work from the corrupted workspace as well (manually).

Assuming you don't have it under version control...

Remove the `.idea\workspace.xml` file (which should only contain non-critical info about the project, like which files were open, in which position, window size and location, etc). Start pycharm and watch for complaints. If the `.idea\workspace.xml` file was the only one corrupted you should be back in business.

If not then wipe the entire `.idea` subdir to erase all traces of the project being a pycharm project before. Then create a new pycharm project by [Importing Project from Existing Source Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/importing-project-from-existing-source-code.html):

> **To create a new project from existing source code**
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose **File | Open**.
> 2. In the [dialog that opens](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/select-path-dialog.html), select the directory that contains the desired source code. Note that applications created externally are
>      marked with the regular directory icon folder.
> 3. Click **OK**.
> 4. Specify whether you want the new project to be opened in a separate window or close the current project and reuse the existing
>      one. Refer to the section [Opening Multiple Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/opening-multiple-projects.html) for details.

This should re-create the `.idea` dir, but with some default project settings. You could re-do all configuration changes inside pycharm.

But you could also try to go even further and check the diffs between the files in the new project's `.idea` dir and the old ones (which you can find in a clone of the backed-up project dir) - you might be able to restore some of the customisations you had in the old project by manually modifying the new project's config files. Be sure to exit pycharm while attempting this - it doesn't like its config files being modified while it's running. And be careful so that you don't cause new corruptions yourself. Make backup copies of the files that you intend to modify manually so that you can easily revert any incorrect changes. To test the changes try to start pycharm and watch for complaints.